# Is it possible to manipulate certain types of characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In this string, `You need, need not want, to complete this code-wars mission`, how can I only select and change alphabetic characters while leaving the commas, spaces, and hyphen characters there?

Comment: how are you trying to change them?

Comment: I'm trying to abbreviate each word, but I'm having trouble leaving non-alphabetic characters in the string while changing each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to select different parts of the string. For example: `[a-zA-Z]+/g` will select all alphabetic characters whereas `[abc]+/g` will only select the characters `a`, `b`, and `c` (though not necessarily right in a row). To replace them/change those characters you can do something like `myString.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/g, '5');` to replace all groups of characters with the number `5`.

Comment: Can you recommend a good resource to learn regular expressions, please?

Comment: @PurpleYoshiii https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. If this answer is correct can you please mark it as so? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to abbreviate each word in the input string. The abbreviated version of the word should have the first letter, then the number of removed characters, then the last letter (eg. "c2e-w2s" for "code-wars"). Is it possible to use `Object.prototype.replace()` to manipulate only the first word, skip the comma/space, manipulate the next word, and so on...?

Comment: yes it is. That would be a good exercise to learn regular expressions. A slightly simpler way would be to use a for loop and a counter